# Как добавить textView в начало заполненного LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Добавляю textview'шки в LinearLayout таким образом:

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ololo);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView textView = new TextView(messages.this);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);                                                
//textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_message_from);                                                
//textView.setText(message_enc_from_key);                                                
////textView.setText(decrypt(hex2Byte(message_enc_from_key), private_key_my));
textView.setText(date_time);
textView.setTextSize(20);
linearLayout.addView(textView, params);
```

Всё работает без нареканий но вот как мне после добавления нескольких textview добавить ещё несколько, но только в начало LinearLayout? ведь метод:

```
linearLayout.addView(textView, params);
```

добавляет их в конец.

Comment: `textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);  `

Comment: setGravity а причём тут это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляйте, указывая индекс так:

```
public void addView(View child, int index)
```

т.е. в вашем cлучае

```
linearLayout.addView(view, 0);
```